# On a proof regarding linear sub-spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $B_1,B_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be two linearly independent vectors and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Take $B_1$ and multiply it by $A$ until the resulting vector is linearly dependent on the previous. One obtains the following set of linear independent vectors:
$$ \{B_1, A\cdot B_1, ..., A^{r_1-1}\cdot B_1\}$$ Let $S_1$ denote the subspace generated by them: 
$$ S_1 = \langle B_1, ..., A^{r_1-1}\cdot B_1 \rangle$$
we have $A^{r_1} \cdot B_1 \in S_1$. Then assuming $B_2$ does not belong to the subspace generated by the above vectors, consider the following subspace:
$$ \bar{S}_1 = \langle B_1, ..., A^{r_1-1}\cdot B_1, B_2, ... , A^{r2-1}\cdot B_2\rangle$$ such that $A^{r_2}\cdot B_2 \in \bar{S}_1$

### Question 1

Assume $r_2 \leq r_1$
Is it true, or possible to prove that actually
$$ A^{r_2} \cdot B_2 \in \langle B_1, ..., A^{r_2-1}\cdot B_1, A^{r_2} \cdot B_1, B_2, ..., A^{r_2-1}\cdot B_2\rangle$$ that is $A^{r_2}\cdot B_2$ does not depend on higher powers of $A$? We can eventually assume that $r_1 + r_2 = n$ ...

### A sketch of my thoughts

Consider the set
$$ S_k = \{B_1, ..., A^{k-1}\cdot B_1\} \cup \{B_2, ..., A^{k-1}\cdot B_2\}$$
The vectors in this set are linear dependent for $k > \frac{n}{2}$ while the vectors in the set 
$$ S_{r_2} = \{B_1, ..., A^{r_2-1}\cdot B_1\} \cup \{B_2, ..., A^{r_2-1}\cdot B_2\}$$ are linear independent. Let $\underline{k} \in [r_2, \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil] \cap \mathbb{N}$ be the lowest number such that $S_{\underline{k}}$ contains linear dependent vectors. We should prove that $\underline{k} = r_2+1$ Moreover, it can be safely assumed, that $\underline{k} \in (r_2, r_1) \cap \mathbb{N}$. Therefore $\underline{k} \in [r_2, \min\{r_1,\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil\}]\cap \mathbb{N}$

It can be easily be shown that such a $\underline{k}$ has the property that for all $k \geq \underline{k}$ the set $S_k$ contains linearly dependent vectors, and for all $k < \underline{k}$ the set $S_k$ contains linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the Question 1 is no. Here is a counterexample. Take $n=4$ and let's denote by $e_i$ the i$^{\text{th}}$ vector of the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^4$. If $B_1=e_1$, $B_2=e_4$ and if $$AB_1=e_2, \;A^2B_1=e_3,\;A^3B_1=e_1$$ and $AB_2=e_3$ then $$r_1=3,\;r_2=1<r_1$$ but $\langle B_1, AB_1, B_2\rangle$ doesn't contain $AB_2=e_3$.

**Edit:** The matrix A is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1&0\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Please give an A

Comment: Look at my edit above.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge and time!

Comment: sir, would the property hold true with the additional requirement that the matrix $A$ should be nonsingular ?